# Kendo MultiSelect in grid no show default values

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, show

I use kendo MultiSelect as custom editor in kendo grid ,
MultiSelect work correctly when save changes but no show textvalue when press edit row button (MultiSelect is empty).

my custom editor function is:

```
function GRID_MULTISELECT_CUSTOM_EDITOR(container, options) {
    var columnValue = String(options.model.POST_HISTORY).replace(/,/g,'","');

    $('<input  name="GRID_POST_LVL_MULTISELECT" id="GRID_POST_LVL_MULTISELECT"  data-value-primitive="true" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            filter: "contains",
            optionLabel: " ",
            width: "100px",
            dataTextField: "NAME_UNIT",
            dataValueField: "CD_UNIT",
            dataSource: prsListDataSource,
            value: [columnValue],
            change: function(e) {
                selectedValue = e.sender.value();
                apex.event.trigger($("#PRS_LIST_REG_POST_HISTORY_MULTISELECT"),"kapex-multiselect-change");
                apex.event.trigger($("#PRS_LIST_REG_POST_HISTORY_MULTISELECT"),"kapex-multiselect-databound");
            }
    });

    var ms = $("#GRID_MULTISELECT_CUSTOM_EDITOR").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    console.log(ms.value());
}
```

`console.log(ms.value());` show value is set but textvalue no show in MultiSelect widget.

When 1 value is stored in database MultiSelect work correctly and textvalue show in edit. but when sotre multi value, textvalue not show.

I store datavalue with this format in database column as varchar.

001,100,110,111,112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to serialize the `POST_HISTORY` values as arrays to the client. This will spare the need to modify the model value on the fly in the custom editor function. You will also don't need to think how to transform the MultiSelect's array value back to a comma-separated string value after the user finishes editing a row.

http://dojo.telerik.com/IDUBI

Keep in mind that using the `value` configuration in the MultiSelect declaration will not work in this case, because the MVVM value binding is applied at a later stage and takes precedence.

On the other hand, if you absolutely need to serialize the `POST_HISTORY` values as comma-separated strings to the client, then use [`dataSource.schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) to transform these strings to arrays **before** the Grid is databound:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OQAGa

Finally, create the MultiSelect widget from a `<select multiple>`, not `<input>`.

Comment: Good, please consider marking my reply as an answer or upvoting it.